# Access private network through ssh when port forwarding is disabled

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, socks-proxy

I have access to a machine A which allows nothing but ssh command. Port forwarding is also disabled there. I can ssh into machine A (on port 5022). From machine A, I can ssh into machine B (port 22), which is connected to the intranet of my university.

I wanted to access an internal webpage of the univ using machine B on my laptop using SOCKS5 proxy on firefox. How do I do that? (I can access machine B only through machine A)
(I think that something similar to http://blog.wrouesnel.com/articles/SSH%20port%20forwarding%20when%20AllowTCPForwarding%20is%20disabled/ 
should work but I am not sure).

Comment: What do you mean by "port forwarding is disabled there"? That's part of the ssh command...

Comment: What OS are you on? If Windows, I think you'll need multiple route add commands. But not sure if route also does port forwardings.

Comment: Have you explored SSH tunnels?

Comment: @grawity on machine A, `AllowTCPPortForwarding` is set to `no`.

Comment: @user3558931 I tried that, but machine A won't allow it

Comment: Where are you creating the tunnels? How you connect to machine A determines what form the tunnels take but they should be created on the local machine. Are you getting an error message?